# Activiti BPMN files handling, diagrams are blank after sharing them in RTC

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, activiti, bpmn, rtc

I'm using **Eclipse Neon v4.6.0** with **Activiti Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer** (v5.18.0.201508100929 - org.activiti.designer.feature.feature.group) to create some Activiti diagrams.

I'm also using **RTC** to cooperate with my job mates. (Plugin name: Rational Team Concert Client Feature v4.5.200.RTC-I20140807-0233 - com.ibm.team.rtc.client.feature.feature.group).

I've made a Java Project in my Eclipse workspace where I put all my Activiti diagrams (bpmn files).
This project was placed under source control by right-clicking and executing 'Team > Share Project' to store the project to a RTC Component of a stream.

Unfortunately, in this state of source control via RTC, **Activiti diagrams are no longer displayed in the visual editor**. The palette is present on the right however the editing pane is blank. Opening the raw XML in a text editor shows that the diagram content is still present in the .bpmn file.

I've also noticed that before adding the project folder to RTC stream, I can open and edit my diagrams fine...but after sharing project in RTC, diagrams don't show anymore.

As a temporary (and awful) workaround I have to copy diagrams in a local folder that is not part of the RTC stream and after editing diagrams in the local folder, I have to copy the diagrams back to the RTC stream manually.

Anyone have the same problem and know how to fix it? 
Thanks in advance